# Clarification on Masking Bits

Tags: binary, bitmask

I have a quick question about masking bits. If I want to turn two 8 bit streams on, do I

use the `AND` logic against the two:

```
     10101010
AND  01101001
     ________
     00101000
```

or do I actually change one of the bits in the stream to turn the bits on? I guess my question is when I'm turning on (using `AND`) or turning off (using `OR`) do I actually change any of the bits, or just comparing the two using the `AND/OR` logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "turning on"? The way you use the term shows either a deep misunderstanding, or a nonstandard usage.

Comment: i think i would just take a bit stream (say 10101010) and change the 4th bit by adding a 01010101 and placing those two in and AND or OR logic?

Comment: i think '00001000' turns on the 4th bit and '11110111' turns off the 4th bit?

Comment: ANDing with 00001000 turns off all but the 4th bit. If the 4th bit is 0 it will stay 0, if it is 1 it will stay 1. Apply the truth table for AND to the individual bits if you find it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To turn ON (1), you would use the OR operator with a 1 in the position you want to turn ON, because no matter what the original value in the stream is, the result would be ON

```
   00000000 // whatever the values in the input
OR 00000001 // 'OR' turns on the last position in the stream
   --------- 
   00000001
```

To turn OFF (0), you would use the AND operator with a 0 in the position you want to turn OFF, because no matter what the original value in the input stream, the result would be OFF.

```
    11111111 // whatever the values here
AND 11111110 // turns off the last position in the stream
    ---------
    11111110
```

Answer (score 0):

Others, correct me if I am wrong:

To turn ON the 4th bit in an 8bit stream you would compare the 8bit stream using the `OR` logic using `00001000`.

To turn OFF the 4th bith in an 8bit stream you would compare the 8bit stream using the `AND` logic using `11110111`.

To toggle the bit you would use `11111111` using the `XOR` logic.

Comment: That `XOR` would toggle every bit in the "stream".

Comment: @Sapph, yes correct. So if i want to turn on a specific bit I would use `00000001` (with this placing the first bit that we are comparing against this steam) into an `AND` logic scenario, but I can also use this method when simply comparing two bit streams (not trying to turn on/off one single bit)?

Comment: No, XOR logic would not have the intended 'toggle' result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'streams' in this case.

In most languages you are going to have to have an assignment as well as the binary operation.

That is you would typically have something like

```
foo = get_byte() // Call some function to get the original value of foo
foo = foo AND 11110111 // Replace foo with the result of the AND, which
                       // in this case will turn off the 4th bit, and leave
                       // the other bits unchanged
```

The last line replaces the contents of foo with the results of the binary operation